# How do I add multiple rows in a table?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sqlcommand

```
string date = p_text_data.Text;
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Warehouse (title,count,price,date) ";
try
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectToDataBase.GetConnection())
    {
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);
        for (int i = 0; i < mdc.Count; i++)
        {
            sql += "SELECT @title" + i + ",@count" + i + ",@price" + i + ",@date" + i + " ";
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title" + i, mdc[i].Title);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count" + i, mdc[i].Count);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price" + i, mdc[i].Price);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date" + i, Conver_Data(date));
            if (mdc.Count-1 != i)
                sql += "UNION ALL ";
        }
        sql += " ;";
        connection.Open();// *sql
        string id_Partner = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
    }
}
catch (SqlException se)
{
    MessageBox.Show(se.Message);
}
```

*sql = "INSERT INTO Warehouse (title,count,price,date) SELECT @title0,@count0,@price0,@date0 UNION ALL SELECT @title1,@count1,@price1,@date1  ;"

Then he flies an exception

> Incorrect syntax near ')'

clarify - count - int, price - double, date - Date

what am I doing wrong?

edit:
Table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Warehouse] (
  [ID] int IDENTITY(1, 1) NOT NULL,
  [title] char(30) COLLATE Cyrillic_General_CI_AS NULL,
  [count] int NULL,
  [price] float NULL,
  [date] datetime NULL,
  CONSTRAINT [PK__Warehous__3214EC277F60ED59] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID])
)
ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

I'm used **SQL Server 2008**

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you using?

Comment: The query works fine for me in SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you are never updating the SQL command text of the `command` object with anything after the ")". Just because you update the `sql` variable doesn't mean that `SqlCommand` object is going to see that update.

(Another problem that you will run into is that you are not returning anything from this query, so you won't be able to use `ExecuteScalar()`.)

Try this instead:

```
string date = p_text_data.Text; 
string sql = @"INSERT INTO Warehouse (title,count,price,date) "; 
try 
{ 
    using (SqlConnection connection = ConnectToDataBase.GetConnection()) 
    { 
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection); 
        for (int i = 0; i < mdc.Count; i++) 
        { 
            sql += "SELECT @title" + i + ",@count" + i + ",@price" + i + ",@date" + i + " "; 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@title" + i, mdc[i].Title); 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@count" + i, mdc[i].Count); 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@price" + i, mdc[i].Price); 
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@date" + i, Conver_Data(date)); 
            if (mdc.Count-1 != i) 
                sql += "UNION ALL "; 
        } 
        sql += " ;"; 
        command.CommandText = sql;    //  Set your SQL Command to the whole statement.
        connection.Open();// *sql 
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();    //  Execute a query with no return value.
    } 
} 
catch (SqlException se) 
{ 
    MessageBox.Show(se.Message); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the String `sql` as a reference type, although it is a reference type, it is a special case where it acts like a value type. The line

`sql += "SELECT @title" + i + ",@count" + i + ",@price" + i + ",@date" + i + " ";`

appears to be appending to `sql` but in fact it is creating a new string, stored in a different location in memory to `String` that you passed to the `SqlCommand`.

If you array is large you may see a performance benefit by using the [StringBuilder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.stringbuilder.aspx) class to build your string then assign it to your `SqlCommand` object after it has been built.

Either way you need to assign it to `SqlCommand.CommandText` after you have the complete SQL in your `sql` variable.